# Simple MVC/JQuery problem

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

... but it is bothering me!
I have 2 checkboxes, and I want to stop then both being checked. So if I check one, the other must be unchecked. 
This might look like a toggle. However they can both be unchecked.
However the real problem is that the click event on the Checkbox is not being picked up.
I cannot understand why, so I hope you can let me know.
This is the View, of which I have tried both the click and change events on the checkbox;

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<TestApp.Models.Checkboxes>" %>

<asp:Content ID="aboutTitle" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    About Us
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="aboutContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Checkbox1').click(function () {
                if ($('#Checkbox1').is(':checked'))
                    $('#Checkbox2').attr(':checked', false);
            })
        });
    </script>
    <h2>About</h2>
    <p>
        Checkboxes Test
    </p>
    <p>
        <%: Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Checkbox1) %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%: Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Checkbox2) %>
    </p>    

</asp:Content>
```

*** ADDED INFO ***

The Page Source looks like this;

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>

    About Us

</title><link href="../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /></head>

<body>
    <div class="page">

        <div id="header">
            <div id="title">
                <h1>My MVC Application</h1>

            </div>

            <div id="logindisplay">

        Welcome <b>Admin</b>!
        [ <a href="/Account/LogOff">Log Off</a> ]

            </div> 

            <div id="menucontainer">

                <ul id="menu">              
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>

                    <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="main">

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Checkbox1').click(function () {
                if ($('#Checkbox1').is(':checked'))
                    $('#Checkbox2').attr(':checked', false);
            })
        });
    </script>
    <h2>About</h2>

    <p>
        Checkboxes Test
    </p>
    <p>
        <input id="Checkbox1" name="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="Checkbox1" type="hidden" value="false" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input id="Checkbox2" name="Checkbox2" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="Checkbox2" type="hidden" value="false" />
    </p>    



            <div id="footer">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what does the rendered version look like?

Comment: This is a test app to try and get this to work. So on my page all I see is some text and the 2 checkboxes that I want to test.

Comment: To clarify, what does the rendered HTML look like, can you post that?  - Specifically the checkbox paragraphs.

Comment: the point @Nick Craver is making is that your assigning the click event based on the ID's, which we cannot see (can only see with the rendered version). Try assigning the checkbox *classes* and assign the click handlers that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's start with the big problem: **jQuery isn't included on the page**, you'll want to add the `<script>` block for this, for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.js"></script>
```

Use your console to see obvious errors like this, you're undoubtedly getting a `$` is not defined error.

---

After that, I think you want `change` here, as well as `'checked'` for the attribute, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#Checkbox1').change(function () {
     $('#Checkbox2').attr('checked', false);
  });
  $('#Checkbox2').change(function () {
     $('#Checkbox1').attr('checked', false);
  });
});
```

[You can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/jvwPN/).  If there was a change, it was *from* checked in which case none should be checked, or it was to checked...either way all *others* should be unchecked.

Or, as a more general solution, put them both in a container, say `<div class="checkOne">` then you can do this for all occurrences:

```
$(function() {
  $(".checkOne :checkbox").change(function() {
    $(this).closest(".checkOne").find(":checkbox")
           .not(this).attr("checked", false);
  });
});
```

[You can try that version here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/jvwPN/1/).

Comment: The perils of writing a quick test app! OK I have put in the JQuery reference and now the event is being picked up as click. What I am finding in Firebug is that the checkbox value is not updating, it is always false. When I look at the page source, it is true. I think the problem may be with the hidden field, and maybe I should use a class as suggested elsewhere

Comment: @arame3333 - Are you using my other changes above, or just including jQuery with your current code?

Comment: You code executes when I use click rather than change. However it does not work. I am not sure how the .not(this).attr("checked", false) works. This line does not in any case ever get executed.

Comment: @arame3333 - it's a chain of the line above, just wrapped to fit on SO without scrolling...it's all one line.

Comment: I have looked around and I notice there is an issue with checkboxes in MVC. It uses a hidden field which you can see in the page source. I think I need to tag this with the MVC community.

Comment: in my experience, when you're chaging a value of a hidden input, Firebug does not always update it for some reason, although the value IS updated... quick check: put "javascript:alert($('#your_hidden_field').attr('checked'))" into the address bar and hit Enter

Comment: That helped me fix the problem. Thank you. The solution works in the simplest form if you replace change with click.

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at it, I don't think you should have the : with the .attr() command.

Have you tried:

`$('#Checkbox2').attr('checked', false);`